# Samba: check file for completeness

Tags: networking, filesystem, samba

I have a device (with Ubuntu on it) with Samba installed.  There is also a cron job that copies files out of the Samba share every 60 seconds.  I am now running into a situation where the cron job sometimes moves incomplete files--as in the file is still being streamed to from over the network.  This especially happens when the files are very large.

Is there a way to check for completeness of a file?  Or, is there a Samba setting that will lock the file (keep it from being moved) till it is complete?

Comment: You can use `openssl dgst -md5 [filename]` to generate a hash from both files and check whether they are equal. As for locking, I would write a script that first checks whether another copy is already running (e.g. by checking for the existence of a lock file) and if so, quietly exits. And use `rsync` to move only those portions of the file that have actually been changed.

Comment: I am assuming you mean checksum it on both ends.  I have no control over the sending machines.  I didn't know there was a lock file.  I'll do a test and see what I can find out about the lock file using `watch -n 0.2 ls -l` or something.

Comment: What I meant was: write a script that creates its own lock file if it doesn't exist, and exits if it does. There are no existing lock files that you can use in a Samba system.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not catching it.  How would I create a lock file with a script for a file that is being dropped into a samba share over the network?

Comment: Short of writing the script for you, the logic of it would be: `if [not exists lock file] (write lock file; copy  large files; remove lock file; exit) else exit` The location of the lock file doesn't matter, and it doesn't need to have any content. Just the fact that a file with a known name and location exists, is a sign that no second attempt should be made to copy the file.

Comment: I probably didn't make my problem clear. Person in remote office drops very large file into a Samba share (he drags-and-drops the file from his Windows machine). While the file is being streamed from his computer to my host over the slow network, my cron job `mv`s the incomplete file before it is finished streaming.  Putting lock file logic in my cron job doesn't really help it know whether the file I am `mv`ing is complete (finished streaming over the network) or not.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Until the file transfer is completed, the file will be in use (opened) by the Samba process. You can test for that by doing `if ! fuser /my/file
then mv /my/file /somewhere/else fi `. Will this work?

Comment: That might work.  You might make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the file transfer is completed, the file will be in use (opened) by the Samba process. You can test for that by means of the `fuser` command. So your move command would be something like:

```
if [[ ! fuser /my/file ]]; then 
    mv /my/file /somewhere/else 
fi
```

This will only attempt to move the file if the file is closed, which means that the transfer was completed.